# Can somebody explain how this piezo-driver circuit works?

Tags: voltage, resonance, piezo-buzzer

[image]

The source is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOZi3QnnDCo). I have countless number of questions about this schematic but there is the most pressing ones:

1. Why L1 is connected to SP1 in such a strange way (right in the middle, and not on the same line with MOSFET's drain?
2. Why there is 100 nF C1 capacitor in there? What is it achieving? Isn't SP1 a capacitor itself (2 thin metal plates sandwiching piezo-ceramic disk? For example, I measured my piezo-transducer (albeit a bit smaller one) and it has capacitance of 3 nF. Why add additional capacitor? To decrese overall capacitance via caps connected in series? Wouldn't it mess up resonance?
3. About resonance, is it even suppose to be resonant circuit here? I understand that it is done to boost voltage via L1 canceling SP1's (and C1's??) voltage because of different phases, decreasing impedance and increasing current, thus increasing voltage on individual caps/inductors. However, after some calculations, I figured out that if it really was resonant, it would result in huge current of few Amps (SP1 has low resonant impedance of about 150 Ohm), which will result in voltage much higher than rated voltage for a transducer like this, thus destroying it. This could be avoided by adding resistor in RLC circuit, but I don't see any resistors here.

Other things is not as important, but if you find any spare time to explain other parts of schematic I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

1. To boost the voltage higher. When transistor turns on, voltage at drain will be about 0V and current starts to increase in the inductor, storing energy. When transistor turns off suddenly, the inductor will dump the stored energy into the piezo disc, rising the voltage as high as necessary to make the current decrease back to 0.
2. Piezo discs usually do not tolerate a DC voltage bias. Therefore it is best to block DC bias with a capacitor. It has nothing to do with resonance.
3. No, it does not look like a resonant circuit, as there is no feedback. The transistor is just driven with a square wave which then drives the piezo.

The other parts of the schematic is nothing out of the ordinary, it's just a NE555 connected as square wave generator to drive the FET gate.

Comment: What is "DC bias"?

Comment: @user263983 I simply meant that the long term average voltage must be 0V, so the DC component is 0V, so there is only AC voltage signal driving the piezo. The capacitor blocks DC voltage, and passes AC voltage.

Comment: OK all this makes sense, but how can inductor boost voltage without a resonant circuit? Just by itself?

Comment: Also, given that piezo is capacitor itself, wouldn't it cancel DC bias without C1?

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer Imagine that there is no C1 and transistor is off forever - there will be DC voltage of VCC applied to piezo forever, and even when transistor is switching, the voltage would be always either 0V or larger than 0V so on average some positive DC component will be present always. And inductor voltage U = L * dI/dt so the faster the rate of current change is the larger voltage is output.

Comment: @Justme But, according to Kirchhoff’s Voltage Law, " for a closed loop series path the algebraic sum of all the voltages around any closed loop in a circuit is equal to zero". So where the hell additional voltage on the inductor comes from, if there is no resonance to compensate? This doesn't make any sense!

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer OK so understanding this circuit must involve understanding inductors which might warrant a question of its own. But in short, inductors store store energy into magnetic field and inductors try to maintain constant current through them. By applying voltage over an inductor by turning on the FET, current starts to rise to some value like 100mA. Then when you turn the FET off, the inductor tries to keep 100mA flowing so the collapsing magnetic field will try to increase voltage to make 100mA flow and it can be very high. That's why inductive loads make arcs when switched off.

Answer (score 2):

A SPICE simulation will show you what's happening. This sort of circuit works well with a low duty cycle (*on* time is shorter than *off* time) driving source which will cause the transducer complex impedance to resonant with the inductor. To fully understand the circuit, you need to know the complex impedance which you don't give, however, we can make an over simplified approximation of the transducer complex impedance which is a capacitor in parallel with a resistor. You can see in the LTspice simulation that you get a sinusoid with a little glitch where the transistor turns on briefly to dump energy in to the tank circuit. I assumed that you are using a 40kHz transducer, thus, I used a 72nF capacitor for the simulated transducer reactive component. Your capacitance measurement is probably the simple capacitance (capacitance measured at a frequency much less than the resonant frequency). The capacitance at the resonant frequency is different than the simple capacitance.

In my simulation, I put the transducer in parallel with the inductor which makes visualization of the circuit topology easier to understand. It is AC equivalent to your schematic as long as you have a bypass capacitor on the power supply.

You are right that you don't need C1 unless the transducer has a transformer built in. An ohmmeter will suss this out.

[image]

Comment: One thing I know for sure, is that in transducer I have on my hands, manufacturer states of max 150 Ohm resonant impedance. Can "complicated" capacitance be calculated from this? Also in normal capacitors what is the value stated on them? Simple or "complex" capacitance? Wouldn't 100 nF cap still be 100 nF cap, just with different impedance on different frequencies?

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer If you want to do an analysis, you need to measure the complex impedance at resonance which can be done using a function generator, oscilloscope and a series resistor (used to measure current). However, you can connect an inductor, perhaps 220uH, in series with the transducer and determine resonance by determining at what frequency where the voltage across the transducer peaks. A function generator and oscilloscope makes this trivial to do.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer A transducer has complex (real & reactive) impedance primarily due to the acoustic resonance(s). A standard capacitor, like a 100nF cap, has a complex impedance, but often we tend to omit that there is a loss (real impedance) component since the loss component is fairly small. In high current, high frequency, and high-accuracy designs, you need to consider all the parameters (capacitance, loss, inductance, dielectric issues) of a capacitor.